# C gets code will not segfault on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows

**VULNERABLE CODE DO NOT USE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char buf[8]; // buffer for eight characters
gets(buf); // read from stdio (sensitive function!)
printf("%s\n", buf); // print out data stored in buf
return 0; // 0 as return value
}
```

I am using the above code (from OWASP https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_overflow_attack ) that simply will not seg fault.

I do what the OWASP input shows but cmd just prints it out and exits. No seg fault. Is windows hiding the exception?

Comment: You probably just got lucky. Try entering a longer string and it should crash. It did for me as expected. Compiled with GCC on Win7 and no optimizations.

Comment: Did you try this in debug or release? Sometimes buffers are over-allocated in debug and - as @jpw wrote - you may have been just lucky.

Comment: @xxbbcc Not sure what you mean by debug or release. Compiled with gcc, c11 standard, no debug symbols etc

Comment: Just think about "**undefined**" as in "_undefined behaviour_".

Comment: @Zimm3r was it a debug build or a release build? (Were optimizations enabled, etc.?) Different compilers may have different standard libraries and they may have a different allocation behavior between a debug and a release build. This may (not necessarily) hide buffer overrun errors (by overallocating a buffer). Typically you'd get some kind of warning upon application exit. Or you just happened to be lucky.

Comment: C *never* guarantees a seg fault under any circumstances. The closest it comes is to call something "undefined behavior", which means *anything* can happen, from appearing to work perfectly to seg fault to [demons flying out your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: @MarkRansom of course C standard don't know anything about segfault, it is OS that guarantees segfault if you access wrong pages. Hard to tell for sure if code in question really doing it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only seg fault if you try to access something your program is not allowed to read/write. Since your array's allocated on the stack (IIRC this is implementation defined, but it probably is), you probably have a reasonable amount of space you can buffer overflow before it seg faults.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, windows call this 'access violation', so it is very unlikely you'll ever see "segmentation fault" message here. Fost likely there will be debugger popup (if you have one registered) or just "program stopped unexpectedly" thing.

Second, segfault happens when you access memory pages in a wrong way (usually when you don't have permissions to). While code presented is surely faulty, it doesn't do that directly. By overflowing buffer, you smash stack (since it grows backwards) and corrupting return address. When `main` finishes, it will try to return - and where it will jump depends on data you've written into buffer. While it is very unlikely you've hit some good value and actually jumped somewhere permitted, it is possible.

Comment: Wouldn't he have to overwrite the saved RBP pointer before he overwrote the return address?

Comment: @BobbySacamano not sure I get what you mean. Yes, but it is right after buf => first thing to be broken. Depends on compiler, of course.